# Interactive debugging with nosetests in PyDev

Tags: python, debugging, pylons, pydev, nose

I'm using PyDev ( with Aptana ) to write and debug a Python Pylons app, and I'd like to step through the tests in the debugger.

Is it possible to launch nosetests through PyDev and stop at breakpoints?

Comment: See the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191146/pydev-nosetests-test-run

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i do to run nosetests using eclipse Pydev (Hope this will help you).

first of all i create a python script and i put it in the root of my package directory :

```
--Package
    |
    | -- runtest.py
    |
    | -- ... (others modules)
```

and in runtest.py i put:

```
import nose
nose.main()
```

now i go to in the menu **Run -> Run configurations** and i create a new configuration of **Pydev Django** i choose my package and put runtest.py in the **main Module** , next i go to arguments tab in the same widget and i put in **Program arguments** the path to my project and different arg to pass to the script example:

```
/home/me/projects/src --with-doctest  # Run doctests too
```

now after clicking on **Apply** i can run this configuration .

For debugging you can run this configuration in debug mode and put your break point anywhere in your code and you can use the terrific debug widget to do several action : step into, to see vars ...

N.B : for doctests sadly i don't think you can put breakpoint in the line of doctest but what you can do is to put your breakpoint in the def of the function that is called by the doctest and like that you can use the debug mode .

Comment: So this doesn't actually integrate it with unittest runner plugin - you don't get the results into plugin view, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try `import pydevd; pydevd.settrace()` where would like a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, somewhat - that is, I don't have breakpoints and stepping working but I do get PyDev to run the tests and show the results in the PyUnit view.

When you run the unit test you'll have to override the test runner to use "nose" and command line arguments "--with-pylons=path/to/test.ini" in the arguments tab of the run configuration.  For example I set it to "--with-pylons=../../test.ini".  Unfortunately I have to set this up separately for each test I run, I haven't found a way to put a variable or project path in there.

Also, unfortunately, I haven't been able to get breakpoints working.  I tried patching as recommended in http://pydev.blogspot.ca/2007/06/why-cant-pydev-debugger-work-with.html and its comments to no avail.  YMMV.

In DecoratorTools-1.8-py2.7.egg/peak/util/decorators.py in decorate_assignment(), replace:

```
oldtrace = [frame.f_trace]
```

with

```
oldtrace = [sys.gettrace()]
```