# Is there a way to hook Django's unittest into PyUnit in eclipse?

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev, python-unittest

I've been working on a Django project for the past few weeks now, and it's been fairly smooth sailing. I use Django's `unittest` library to test everything, and the result show up in the console.

However, after doing some research, it looks like pydev provides facilities for `PyUnit`. I use Eclipse, and I thought I would just just be able to pipe the unit tests into PyUnit, but I haven't had any luck in either that or finding documentation to do so.

How do I have my unit tests run in the PyUnit view in eclipse?

Currently, I run all of my test within eclipse using the following:

```
manage.py test
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [Nose](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/) for your django tests.
Pydev allows you to [choose your test runner](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html#configuring-test-runners), and it has support for nose.

I'll let stack explain [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696884/python-nose-vs-unittest) and how to integrate [nose with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087582/interactive-debugging-with-nosetests-in-pydev) for interactive debugging.

And i'll throw in the [django-nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose) too.

Comment: I don't think you can use django-nose, if you want to run the tests inside PyDev's testrunner plugin and see the results in their specific view. At least I had to resort to djangosanetesting, which really integrates into nose command (django-nose seems to do the opposite - it integrates to django's manage.py test action).

Comment: The question was how to have test results displayed in PyDev's PyUnit view. I don't see anything addressing that question in the links you've provided. Is it possible or not?

Comment: This answer is cryptic and contains broken links that doesn't really help decrypt it

Answer (score 1):

Here's an adapter that lets you use the nose plugin from the django-nose package from the command line.  Then you can run your django tests through the Eclipse PyUnit window via nose.

https://github.com/jenniferlianne/django_nose_adapter