# Eclipse with Django Unittest

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev, django-testing

I have a simple set of Django test cases that fail in Eclipse. Specifically if I have something like:

```
resp =self.client.get('/accounts/newUser/')
self.assertEqual(resp.status_code,200)
self.assertTrue('user' in resp.context)
```

then it would fail because resp.context is None. I have managed to get to run from eclipse using `django.test.utils.setup_test_environment()`, but then I have have to do something like `resp.context[0][0][0]['user']` which is less than ideal.

Is there a more clever way to get python unit tests to run from Eclipse? I've seen [this solution using django-nose from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677386/is-there-a-way-to-hook-djangos-unittest-into-pyunit-in-eclipse) and my original solution above [came from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392537/django-unit-test-client-response-has-empty-context).

Comment: I would advice you to change IDE if you need to use one to PyCharm, its magic and awesome.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at PyCharm once, but for $99 on the current version it didn't seem to offer enough on top of eclipse + pydev. At that price I'm willing to deal with a bit of nasty array indexing.

Comment: I'm telling you, its well worth the 99 bucks. I bought it a while back, and part from firing up vim sometimes, I'll never go back to pydev again.