# Can I hook in Django tests results into Eclipse test UI?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I am using pydev to develop a django app in Eclipse. The Django feature to run tests is working great but it only gives feedback in the console and it doesn't create a run-configuration in Eclipse but rather seems to be running separately. Is there a way to run Django tests more integrated with Eclipse and using the PyUnit view?

(I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677386/is-there-a-way-to-hook-djangos-unittest-into-pyunit-in-eclipse) which seems to be similar but the accepted answer is short, cryptic and depends on now broken links)