# pydev nosetests test run

Tags: pydev, nosetests

Seems like a silly question but I've been unable to figure it out...

I'd like to use eclipse/pyunit to run all my tests.  I've configured the test runner to be the nose test runner.

Now I'd like for pyunit to use nose

Comment: I think the accepted answer is not the right one anymore.  Consider changing to the one that says how to select nose.  (I missed that one because I tried following the accepted answer and got distracted.  When I found it on my own, I came back here and kicked myself...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can right-click a folder/file and choose Run as > Python unittest or if you have the file open in an editor, you can use 'Ctrl+F9' to run the tests (and even filter to select the test(s) you want to run).

---

Note: for this to work with nose you have to select the nose test runner in the preferences (window > preferences > pydev > pyunit) -- and the same is true if you're using the py.test runner (but note that if you're using regular unittest tests, the default runner should work fine).

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I see I didn't fully form my question...sorry about that.  I guess what I meant was I'm trying to get Eclipse to use nosetests test discovery so I can run all my tests from eclipse. I am already to use nose to run individual test files, but not more.

Comment: I guess I still didn't understand then... if you already chose the test runner to be the nose test runner, all should be done through nose already when you choose run as > python unittest (are you having some problem doing that?)

Comment: That works but it only runs the tests for a single file.  Whichever file/window has context will have its tests run.  But it doesn't use the discovery mechanism that nosetests from the command line uses to discover and run all the tests.

Comment: You should be able to right click a folder (or even multiple files) and it should do the test discovery on that (which test discovery that nose is doing in the command line you don't have available by doing that?)

Comment: oh, you're right, it works...it was just too straightforward for me to think of. :-)

Answer (score 7):

I found this solution:

1. On the main menu, go to Windows->Preference->PyDev->PyUnit
2. Under "test runner" choose Nose test runner.
3. Apply
4. Ok