# Pydev eclipse breakpoints not working with nose runner

Tags: python, django, eclipse, debugging

I am using Pydev in Eclipse to develop my Django app. I am able to run test inside eclipse as I have configured the debug configuration for it. So when I click on the run/debug button in eclipse, my tests are run. The problem is when I put a breakpoint somewhere in my code and click on the debug button. It get executed but doesn't stop at the break point.

This is part of my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_nose',)

#Test config
# Use nose to run all tests
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'


# Tell nose to measure coverage on the 'foo' and 'bar' apps
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-html',
    '--cover-package=picturesApp,profileApp',
]
```

If I comment the line `TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'` it works as it should.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087582/interactive-debugging-with-nosetests-in-pydev) if I add `import pydevd; pydevd.settrace()` in the test class, it kind of work: the debugger stops where I've added that line and also on the breakpoints. This is not ideal as it stop where I haven't set a breakpoint and also I don't like the idea of having to add it in all my test modules.

Anyone knows how to make it work?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you ever found a solution?